# How do I cut a hole through tile and hardibacker board to access the fireplace hole?

Tags: repair, gas, fireplace, tiling

I have located the fireplace gas hole but there is tile and hardibacker on top of it. I want to see what options I have to cut a new hole around it. I have pictures.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where to drill, a diamond hole saw will do the job.

Comment: This is the answer I would have posted too. But be aware that a diamond hole saw can be tricky for beginners! Practice a few times on a scrap tile! I have found that using a wet masonry sponge works well as a guide, cools the bit, and controls the dust.

Comment: Drill through a piece of thin plywood first to get the hole started, then do the wet sponge trick to keep the bit cool so the tile does not crack in the wrong spot.  The OP needs to know that the keyhole cover only has 1/2" of cover on either side. A little off the mark, and the cover will not cover the drilled hole as it should, therefore requiring a tile to be replaced. Something the tile guy should be doing.....